# Hacer funcionar jQuery en código inyectado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

No consigo hacer funcionar un simple script de alert en una web a la que le inyecto el código.

Primero le meto el jquery.js en head y después el script:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Demo</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="demo">Demo</button>

<script>
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click','#demo',function(){
  alert("Hello World!");
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aclaro que todo esto es código que yo inyecto después de que se cargara la página.
Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Gracias!

Comment: No me queda claro a que te refieres con inyectar el código, tu ejemplo funciona correctamente como esta escrito.

Comment: @emaringolo funciona si cargo la página con ese código desde el principio, pero si por ejemplo a una página ya cargada, modifico el dom y le cargo ese código nuevo, deja de funci0onar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar invocar la función inmediatamente, por ej., si estas retornando el contenido mediante AJAX, puedes inyectar el HTML junto con el `<script>`, de esta manera cuando se evalúe el script podrás hacer algo tipo:

```
(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#demo',function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
})();
```

o directamente:

```
  $(document).on('click','#demo',function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
```

(sin especificarla como IIFE)